# Calculate duration inside groups based on timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, duration

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
| id | device| x | y | z | timestamp |
  1   device_1 22  8   23  2020-10-30T16:00:00.000+0000
  1   device_1 21  88  65  2020-10-30T16:01:00.000+0000
  1   device_1 33  34  64  2020-10-30T16:02:00.000+0000
  2   device_2 12  6   97  2019-11-30T13:00:00.000+0000
  2   device_2 44  77  13  2019-11-30T13:00:00.000+0000
  1   device_1 22  11  30  2022-10-30T08:00:00.000+0000
  1   device_1 22  11  30  2022-10-30T08:01:00.000+0000
```

The data represents events for an "id" on a certain point in time. I would like to see development of values over a period of time to plot a time series for instance.

I'm thinking of adding a column 'duration' which is 0 for the first entry and then the difference in the next entry related to the same id on the same day (there might be multiple different event streams for the same id on separate days).

I would ideally want a dataframe looking something like this:

```
| id | device | x | y | z | timestamp |                  duration |
  1   device_1 22  8   23  2020-10-30T16:00:00.000+0000   00:00.00.000
  1   device_1 21  88  65  2020-10-30T16:01:00.000+0000   00:01:00.000
  1   device_1 33  34  64  2020-10-30T16:02:00.000+0000   00:02:00.000
  2   device_2 12  6   97  2019-11-30T13:00:00.000+0000   00:00:00.000
  2   device_2 44  77  13  2019-11-30T13:00:30.000+0000   00:00:30.000
  1   device_1 22  11  30  2022-10-30T08:00:00.000+0000   00:00:00.000
  1   device_1 22  11  30  2022-10-30T08:01:00.000+0000   00:01:00.000
```

I have no idea where to begin in order to achieve this so either a good explanation or a code example would be very helpful!

Any other suggestions on how to be able to plot development over time (in general not related to a specific date or time of the day) based on this dataframe are also very welcome.

Note: It has to be in PySpark (not pandas) since the dataset is extremely large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use window functions (specific functions working inside partitions created using `over` clause). The below code does the same thing as in the other answer, but I wanted to show a more streamlined version, fully in PySpark, as opposed to PySpark + SQL with subqueries.

Initially, the column "difference" will be of type *interval*, so then it's up to you to try to transform it to whatever data type you need. I have just extracted the interval using `regexp_extract` which stores it as string.

Input (I assume your "timestamp" column is of type *timestamp*):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 'device_1', 22, 8, 23, '2020-10-30T16:00:00.000+0000'),
     (1, 'device_1', 21, 88, 65, '2020-10-30T16:01:00.000+0000'),
     (1, 'device_1', 33, 34, 64, '2020-10-30T16:02:00.000+0000'),
     (2, 'device_2', 12, 6, 97, '2019-11-30T13:00:00.000+0000') ,
     (2, 'device_2', 44, 77, 13, '2019-11-30T13:00:30.000+0000'),
     (1, 'device_1', 22, 11, 30, '2022-10-30T08:00:00.000+0000'),
     (1, 'device_1', 22, 11, 30, '2022-10-30T08:01:00.000+0000')],
    ["id", "device", "x", "y", "z", "timestamp"]
).withColumn("timestamp", F.to_timestamp("timestamp"))
```

Script:

```py
w = W.partitionBy('id', F.to_date('timestamp')).orderBy('timestamp')
df = df.withColumn('duration', F.col('timestamp') - F.min('timestamp').over(w))
df = df.withColumn('duration', F.regexp_extract('duration', r'\d\d:\d\d:\d\d', 0))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---+--------+---+---+---+-------------------+--------+
# |id |device  |x  |y  |z  |timestamp          |duration|
# +---+--------+---+---+---+-------------------+--------+
# |1  |device_1|22 |8  |23 |2020-10-30 16:00:00|00:00:00|
# |1  |device_1|21 |88 |65 |2020-10-30 16:01:00|00:01:00|
# |1  |device_1|33 |34 |64 |2020-10-30 16:02:00|00:02:00|
# |1  |device_1|22 |11 |30 |2022-10-30 08:00:00|00:00:00|
# |1  |device_1|22 |11 |30 |2022-10-30 08:01:00|00:01:00|
# |2  |device_2|12 |6  |97 |2019-11-30 13:00:00|00:00:00|
# |2  |device_2|44 |77 |13 |2019-11-30 13:00:30|00:00:30|
# +---+--------+---+---+---+-------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem can be resolved using Window functions a below

```
  from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.Builder().getOrCreate()
    
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (1,'device_1',22,8,23,'2020-10-30T16:00:00.000+0000'),
            (1,'device_1',21,88,65,'2020-10-30T16:01:00.000+0000'),
            (1,'device_1',33,34,64,'2020-10-30T16:02:00.000+0000'),
            (2,'device_2',12,6,97,'2019-11-30T13:00:00.000+0000') ,
            (2,'device_2',44,77,13,'2019-11-30T13:00:00.000+0000'),
            (1,'device_1',22,11,30,'2022-10-30T08:00:00.000+0000'),
            (1,'device_1',22,11,30,'2022-10-30T08:01:00.000+0000')
        ],
        ("id", "device_name", "x","y","z","timestmp"))
    
    df.show(5, False)
    
    +---+-----------+---+---+---+----------------------------+
    |id |device_name|x  |y  |z  |timestmp                    |
    +---+-----------+---+---+---+----------------------------+
    |1  |device_1   |22 |8  |23 |2020-10-30T16:00:00.000+0000|
    |1  |device_1   |21 |88 |65 |2020-10-30T16:01:00.000+0000|
    |1  |device_1   |33 |34 |64 |2020-10-30T16:02:00.000+0000|
    |2  |device_2   |12 |6  |97 |2019-11-30T13:00:00.000+0000|
    |2  |device_2   |44 |77 |13 |2019-11-30T13:00:00.000+0000|
    +---+-----------+---+---+---+----------------------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df_1 = df.withColumn("timestmp_t", to_timestamp(col("timestmp")))
df_1 = df_1.withColumn("date_t", to_date(substring(col("timestmp"), 1, 10)))
df_1.show(5)

+---+-----------+---+---+---+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
| id|device_name|  x|  y|  z|            timestmp|         timestmp_t|    date_t|
+---+-----------+---+---+---+--------------------+-------------------+----------+
|  1|   device_1| 22|  8| 23|2020-10-30T16:00:...|2020-10-30 16:00:00|2020-10-30|
|  1|   device_1| 21| 88| 65|2020-10-30T16:01:...|2020-10-30 16:01:00|2020-10-30|
|  1|   device_1| 33| 34| 64|2020-10-30T16:02:...|2020-10-30 16:02:00|2020-10-30|
|  2|   device_2| 12|  6| 97|2019-11-30T13:00:...|2019-11-30 13:00:00|2019-11-30|
|  2|   device_2| 44| 77| 13|2019-11-30T13:00:...|2019-11-30 13:00:00|2019-11-30|
+---+-----------+---+---+---+--------------------+-------------------+----------+

df_1.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_table")

spark.sql("""
select t.*, (timestmp_t - min) as duration from (
SELECT id, device_name, date_t, timestmp_t, MIN(timestmp_t) OVER (PARTITION BY id, date_t ORDER BY timestmp_t) AS min
    FROM tmp_table) as t
""").show(5, False)

+---+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
|id |device_name|date_t    |timestmp_t         |min                |duration                           |
+---+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
|1  |device_1   |2020-10-30|2020-10-30 16:00:00|2020-10-30 16:00:00|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00' DAY TO SECOND|
|1  |device_1   |2020-10-30|2020-10-30 16:01:00|2020-10-30 16:00:00|INTERVAL '0 00:01:00' DAY TO SECOND|
|1  |device_1   |2020-10-30|2020-10-30 16:02:00|2020-10-30 16:00:00|INTERVAL '0 00:02:00' DAY TO SECOND|
|1  |device_1   |2022-10-30|2022-10-30 08:00:00|2022-10-30 08:00:00|INTERVAL '0 00:00:00' DAY TO SECOND|
|1  |device_1   |2022-10-30|2022-10-30 08:01:00|2022-10-30 08:00:00|INTERVAL '0 00:01:00' DAY TO SECOND|
+---+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! However, I went with the "pure pyspark" solution so I marked that as the solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).